# Values in map object are not being incremented

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am doing analysis on an array of strings named `wordList: string[] = [];`

This contains a long list of strings.

Problem: I have a map object whose key is a `string` type and value is of type `number`.

Here is my code.

```
private rankMostFrequent5Words(): void {

    this.wordList.forEach((word:string) => {

     if(!this.mapObject.has(word)) {

        this.mapObject.set(word, 1)
     }
     else {
        this.mapObject[word]++;
     }
    });
  }
```

My desired output is: if a key already exists in the map then increment the number by 1 and if it does not exist set this key and count to 1.

Actual output:

[image: What I get in browser console]

How can I fix this ? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access map values with bracket syntax. You must use the `.get` method.

```
if(!this.mapObject.has(word)) {
  this.mapObject.set(word, 1)
} else {
  this.mapObject.set(word, this.mapObject.get(word) + 1)
}
```

Read more about [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: I thought i can access them like C# hash-tables. BTW That worked. I will look into map type.